# How many GB of a USB flash drive can I use to install Xbox 360 games?

Tags: xbox-360

I'm going to buy a USB flash drive for Xbox 360 games to install on. I saw  a 512 GB USB flash drive 2.0 and I'm going to buy it if I will be able to install Xbox 360 games on it. Can I install Xbox 360 games on more then 32GB USB flash drives?

Comment: A 512GB flash drive? Really? *really?*

Comment: @iMAGEbox - You can purchase a 512GB flash drive but the Xbox 360 will only use 32GB of it.

Comment: @tombull89 yes really. stackexchange will not allow me to share info about site. its Chinese only for today(december2) is special sale its 15$ its awesome.

Comment: A 512GB flash drive for $15. Seems *totally* legit.

Comment: @iMAGEbox What a complete load of rubbish!

Comment: Seems almost guaranteed to be a scam; a half terabyte USB stick is legitimately available, but only for triple digits.  I think there's a reason SE won't allow you to share info about the site.

Comment: Chinese site, 512GB for $15 sounds WAY too good to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Microsoft](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/using-usb-flash-drive), drives need to provide at least 1 GB of storage space and must be formatted using the FAT32 file system. You can format up to 2 TB to use on the Xbox 360. Formatting can be done on the console, so the drive doesn't need to be pre-formatted.

> **USB minimum requirements**
>
> To use a USB flash drive with your console, the USB flash drive must meet these requirements:
>   - A minimum of 1 GB storage capacity.
>   - Windows FAT32 file system format

---

According to the [USB flash drive FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/accessories/usb-flash-drive-faq), you can store everything on your flash drive, excluding games for the original Xbox, which need to be stored on an Xbox 360 Hard Drive instead.

Comment: You might want to explain the reason for the 32GB limit.  Xbox 360 uses a modified filesystem based on FAT32 which limits the size of a file to around 4GB.  Xbox 360 also uses 4GB block files to store data.  The 32GB limit is basically there because Xbox 360 won't create more then 8 of these files on a USB device.  If you were to partition a larger size drive, then the limitation in theory, would exist on two seperate partitions.

Comment: Look, youd.have to.Be pretty stupid to think any 10k user didn't know how to edit. Your making a pretty big deal out of questioning my actions when "I didn't feel like it" is a perfectly legitimate reason. I LEFT you a comment to update your answer. If you hadn't made a big deal out of it, I would have reversed my downvote. The answer at least accurate as far as I can tell, there's no real reason to go on about this.

Comment: @Timelord64. I never claimed you didn't know *how* to edit, I assumed you forgot you were *allowed* to in this kind of situation. You downvoted me, which is your right, and I'm grateful for your comment, but why are you saying I'm making a big deal of this, when you're the one blowing things out of proportions? I made a mistake in my assumption, I'm sorry. Do I need to bow down before you, or can we move on?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a 1TB exteral hard disk drive as my memory unit. The system recognizes and allows me to use all of it.

The console will treat USB flash devices the same, but keep in mind that an external hard drive is still very cheap and affordable.

Comment: This is actually correct, as the accepted answer is outdated.